# How to hide navigation toolbar in firefox

Tags: window.open

I have opened a new window like this. I have to hide navigation toolbar in firefox and for that I provided location = no. It doesn't work in firefox. How can I hide the address bar (navigation toolbar)

```
var features = 'height=420,width=320,top=10,left=25,status=no,toolbar=no,location=yes,menubar=no,titlebar=no,scrollbars=yes,modal=yes';

window.open ( path,title,features );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Most modern browsers forbid JavaScript from hiding the address bar in new windows as an anti-phishing measure.

Comment: Actually my issue is that I donot want to show the user the address bar since it contains secure data which is passed as querystring. Can you please tell me whether it is advisable to encode the url

Comment: Anything you give to the browser, you also give to the user. Don't give anything to the browser you don't trust the user with. Keep it on the server and pass a random token (session id) to the browser instead.

Comment: I think using more session objects is complicated. I have used 4 session objects already in my project.

Comment: Then you'll have lots of experience. It doesn't change the fact that there isn't a sane way to give something to the user's browser that you want to keep secret from the user.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted this with my own site and used:

> window.open('URL','Title','width=420,height=320,menubar=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,directories=no');

This got rid of the toolbars but I wasn't able to get rid of the address.

Comment: In response to your comment on David's answer if you are using javascript, unless it is encrypted, odds are the data is already available client side. This may be in the source or the user themselves entered it.

Comment: The code above?  Yeah it does but the user will still be able to see the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to secure data which is passed as querystring - you can use POST method instead of GET method by  specifying method=post in the querystring .